# Make a bootable USB drive that can install both Windows XP and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows, multi-boot, bootable-media

I have ISO images for both Ubuntu and Windows XP. I want to host both of them on a USB drive so that I can install either without needing installation CDs (I don't have a CD drive). How can I do that?

SO, I want to have both Windows XP and Ubuntu on my USB Drive so that i could install any one of tem just from a USB. I do not have CD Drive thats why i wanna do that. I have ISO image of both ubuntu and windows xp

Comment: Take a look at multisystem (http://liveusb.info/dotclear/) the design of the GUI is terrible, the translation is terrible, too, but for me the program works, and that's the important thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been using this for a long time, it never let me down,  you should give it a try.
[YUMI - your universal multiboot installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)